# Gerrit:change authenticate mode from http to ldap

Tags: gerrit

my project recently opted for LDAP authenctication from HTTP, is it possible to change them with out re-running the steps,. or pls let me know how we can do this.

Comment: Which steps? You are very unclear. Do you want to know, if e.g. the same username in HTTP auth and in LDAP makes the switch "seamless" without any user losing his settings, being duplicated etc.?

Comment: you are almost there, as of now i dont have any userbase. yes - i set up my authentication to HTTP and now want to switch to LDAP with out running the initilization step for gerrit.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, however you need to do some manual steps.

Please check out the following link for some hints (it is for OpenId to LDAP migration, but you need to do some manual work in the same database tables):
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/VMpG0k119AY

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, i dont have an access to the DB .So i have no way but re-running the init script for a new site.  I am with an issue there again , i am trying to use ORACLE d/b with gerrit. it defaults to copy ojdbc6 from "Copying file:///u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar ". However the driver is present on a diff path., question is how do i tell gerrit.war to fetch the driver from the path i need to copy.

Comment: If you have no userbase and no DB access, I clearly suggest you to set up a new Gerrit instance.